# Seg Fault 11 when inserting element into binary search tree

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I am writing a program in C++ and I can't figure out why I keep getting a segmentation fault. Here is the part of the code I am currently working with that is causing me trouble:

In my main function:

```
Tree* myTree;
myTree = CreateBST();

const Element a = 23;
InsertBST(myTree, a);

const Element b = 8;   //If I get rid of this line and the next one, the error goes away.
InsertBST(myTree, b);  //But I need to be able to insert data into my tree beyond just the root!
```

And then the insertBST function itself and its helper function:

```
void InsertBST(Tree * rTree, const Element nData){
    rTree->root = InsertNodeBST(rTree->root, nData);
}    

//========================================================================================
TreeNode* InsertNodeBST(TreeNode* rNode, const Element nData)
{
    if(rNode->data == -999)   //A new tree's root->data will always be initialized to -999
   {
       TreeNode* rNew = new TreeNode;
       rNew->data = nData;
       rNew->left = NULL;
       rNew->right = NULL;
       return rNew;
   }
   else if(rNode == NULL)
   {
       TreeNode* rNew = new TreeNode;
       rNew->data = nData;
       rNew->left = NULL;
       rNew->right = NULL;
       return rNew;
   }
   else if(nData == rNode->data)
   {
       return rNode;
   }
   else if(nData < rNode->data)
   {
       rNode->left = InsertNodeBST(rNode->left, nData);
       return rNode;
   }
   else
   {
       rNode->right = InsertNodeBST(rNode->right, nData);
       return rNode;
   }

}
```

The structures we are required to use are as follows:

```
struct TreeNode {
  Element data;
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode *right;
};

struct Tree{
    TreeNode *root;
};
```

Does anyone see what I am clearly missing that could be causing my segmentation fault? I'm new to CS and I am taking my first CS class in 7 years, so I apologize if it is a glaringly obvious mistake. Thanks.

Comment: If you ran it in a debugger it would help you narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: As the previous comment stated, use the debugger.  Also, have your binary tree operations drawn on paper with boxes, lines, etc.  The reason is that when you do use the debugger, you will see where the program deviates from what you had planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (rNode->data == -999)
{
    ...
}
else if (rNode == NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

If `rNode` is `NULL`, `rNode->data` crashes. Did you mean to put these `if`s in the reverse order?

Comment: Ah ha! That was it. I switched them and it works. Oh the embarrassment. Thanks!